# Setup dual monitor Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, multi-monitor, display, resolution

I'm running Linux Mint 19.1 on my Dell e6530 laptop which has a maximum resolution of 1600x900. I have connected an external monitor capable of 1920x1080 via HDMI and set this monitor as primary with 1920x1080 resolution.

However, I want to duplicate (not extend) the screens, so I have 1600x900 on the laptop screen and 1920x1080 on the external and when I set them to duplicate through the display settings, the external monitor inherits the laptop's lower resolution of 1600x900.

```
xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3520 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS-0 connected 1600x900+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1600x900      59.99*+  40.00  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```